# SQL query to convert Date to another format

Tags: sql, oracle, date-conversion

Thanks for your help. I am not able to make out the type/format of the "Value" in a Date column.I guess its in Julian Date format.

The Column  is      **paid_month** and the values are below.

```
                  200901
                  200902
```

So,please help in writing SQL query  to convert the above values(Mostly in Julian Format) in the Date Column to normal date (MM/DD/YYYY) .

Thanks
Rohit

Hi,

I am sorry for missing in giving the whole information.

1)Its a Oracle Database.
2)The column given is Paid_Month with values 200901,200902

3)I am also confused that the above value gives month & year.Day isnt given if my guess is right.

4)If its not in Julian format ,then also please help me the SQL to get at least mm/yyyy

---

I am using a Oracle DB and running the query 
THANKS i GOT THE ANSWER.

****Now,i have to do the reverse meaning converting a date 01/09/2010 to a String which has 6 digits.**
Pls help with syntax-
select to_char(01/01/2010,**

Comment: What database are you using? The functions for converting to date vary between vendors.

Comment: Should say which flavor SQL you are working on....

Comment: I'm guessing `paid_month` is actually a (var)char column, rather than a date(time) column also...

Comment: Or number(6) or int4 or something? year=paid_month/100, month=paid_month % 100, day=01? Where shall the day come from? I agree, we need the DB-vendor, because converting is vendor dependent. And we need to know the format of paid_month. String, number, something else?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like YYYYMM - depending on your database variant, try `STR_TO_DATE(paid_month, 'YYYYMM')`, then format that.

Note: MM/DD/YYYY is not "normal" format - only Americans use it. The rest of the world uses DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: I am using a Oracle DB and running the query  select paid_month = STR_TO_DATE('200901','%Y%m') from dual;

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL check 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you would use the STR_TO_DATE function, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(paid_month,'%Y%m');
```

Sounds like the column contains some normal dates and some YYYYMM dates.  If the goal is to update the entire column, you can attempt to isolate the YYYYMM dates and update only those.  Something like:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET paid_month = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(paid_month, '%Y%m'), '%m/%d/%Y')
WHERE LENGTH(paid_month) = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (paid_month % 100) + "/01/" + (paid_month/100) AS paid_day
FROM tbl;
```

I'm not sure about how oracle concatenates strings. Often, you see || in SQL:

```
SELECT foo || bar FROM ...
```

or functions:

```
SELECT cat (foo, bar) FROM ...
```